# Parameter types in C++ standard library

Tags: c++, pointers, std

I noticed some standard library functions use void* as their parameters, for example, the `memcpy` function, its prototype is :

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

There are also functions using char* as their paramters, for example, the `read` function of `ifstream` class, its prototype is:

```
istream& read ( char* s, streamsize n );
```

Why does not the standard library unify these paramteres, for example, all using char* or all using void*. Are there any particular reasons?

cheng

Comment: `memcpy` is most definitely not an STL function!

Comment: @Pubby   Ok. Let's say it's party of the C++ standard functions.

Comment: The old C functions typically used void pointers for memory locations. That's great and fine, and so do the C++ allocation functions, but void pointers don't lend themselves to pointer arithmetic. Since `char` means "byte" (i.e. "smallest data unit"), `char*` is really an entirely satisfactory replacement type. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers can be implicitly casted to `void*`, but not `char*`. This leads to type safety - if you care about the type then don't use `void*`.

Since `memcpy` is designed to work on pointer types it uses `void*`.
`read` was not designed to work on all pointer types and so it uses `char*`

```
void foo(void* x) {}
void bar(char* x) {}

int main() {
  int* x;
  foo(x);
  bar(x); // error - can't convert int* to char*
}
```